# How can I specify Time Delays in Linear Systems in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, transfer-function, python-control

this was asked 7 years ago in this thread:

[How to define LTI systems with Time delay in Scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451767/how-to-define-lti-systems-with-time-delay-in-scipy)

The answer is outdated or at least I don't know how to make it work, and I would like to know if there is a way of doing this in the present.

I want to create a transfer function that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNZ36.png), where `s` equals 0.1 which is the time delay.

In matlab I would do something like this:

`H=tf(1,'InputDelay',0.1);`

```
s=tf('s');
G=1/(s+1);
Q=1+0.5*s+2/s;
```

so that then I can operate with the transfer functions as follows:

```
M=feedback(Q*G,H);
M=minreal(M);
display(M);
```

I would like to know if there is an equivalent in python. So that I don't have to use symbolic expressions which limit the versatility of the code.

with symbolic expressions it would look like this:

```
s = sym.symbols('s')
G = 1/(s+1)
Q = 1+0.5*s+2/s
H = sym.exp(-0.1*s)
# Cálculo de la función de transferencia global
M = Q*G/(1+Q*G*H)
M = sym.simplify(M)
sym.pprint(M)
```

I thought of using numpy or sympy exp but neither works:

```
s = ct.tf('s')
H = np.exp(-0.1*s)
```

Output:

`TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type TransferFunction which has no callable exp method`

Sympy gives this:

`SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '-0.1 s------  1'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

I've googled for everything I could think of and couldn't find any documentation on this, sorry for my ignorance and poor english.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there are no widely supported control libraries for Python which support delays in the same way as the Matlab control toolbox does. My students and I have been working on a solution for this for a while and hope to package it up for release to pypi this year.

The repository with our code is [here](https://github.com/alchemyst/Skogestad-Python) and the object which allows the kinds of manipulations you're talking about using an internal delay representation is defined in `InternalDelay.py`.

One slight problem with your example is that your Q is not physically realisable, which causes some errors in our library.

The following code will produce a step response for your closed loop system, showing the effect of adding a delay. I've also used only PI control instead of PID to keep the controller physically realisable.

```
from utils import InternalDelay, tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s = tf([1, 0], 1)
G = 1/(s + 1)
Q = 1 + 2/s
H = tf(1, 1, deadtime=0.1)
G = InternalDelay(G)
Q = InternalDelay(Q)
H = InternalDelay(H)
one = InternalDelay(tf(1, 1))

M = Q*G/(one + Q*G)
Mdelay = Q*G/(one + Q*G*H)

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 5000)

y = M.simulate(lambda t: [1], t)
ydelay = Mdelay.simulate(lambda t: [1], t)

plt.plot(t, y, t, ydelay)
plt.legend(['Delay-free', 'Delay=0.1s'])
plt.axhline(1)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you very much! When you say my Q is not physically realizable you mean that your library doesn't accept TFs that are 'invented' or do not represent a real model?

Comment: No, I mean that an ideal PID like this is [improper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Proper_transfer_functions) and therefore cannot be represented by standard state space models.